How to add specific Price so I can implement spread on VectorBT
Hi I wanted to implement my spread like from the current price I will add around 400 points TP and 200 points on SL
here's my current code I'm pretty sure I didn't make it right with the points_to_percentage function
def points_to_percentage(points, point_size=0.00001):
    return points * point_size

pf = vbt.Portfolio.from_signals(
    data['close'],
    entries=long_entries,
    short_entries=short_entries,
    sl_stop=points_to_percentage(400),
    tp_stop=points_to_percentage(200),
    freq='1d',
    upon_opposite_entry='close'
)

print(pf.stats())

